AssertionError: MultiIndex level [1] are different Attribute "inferred_type" are different
I'm trying to asserting the pivot table in pandas dataframe but getting assertion error.
I created a pivot table from a DataFrame as shown below:

solution_df = pd.pivot_table(accidents_df, columns='Traffic_Signal', values=\['Humidity(%)', 'Pressure(in)', 'Visibility(mi)'\], index='City', aggfunc='min', fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Min. of All')

Then, I saved the CSV file with the following code:

solution_df.to_csv('activity_solutions_files/solution_05.csv', index=True)

After that, I read the saved CSV file into a DataFrame `df` using:

df = pd.read_csv('solution_05.csv', index_col=0, header=\[0, 1\])

This results in a similar DataFrame, but when I test the equality using pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(solution_df, df), it throws the following error:

AssertionError: MultiIndex level [1] are different

Attribute "inferred_type" are different 
[left]: mixed 
[right]: string


So what is your question? When you save data to csv and then re-import them, types can change according to the import settings, because csv doen't contain type information. Alternatively you could set check_dtype=False in the assertion.
